# How to access a secondary class on webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a class (`NewPage`) which inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`.

When i create an ASPX page i replace the existing `System.Web.UI.Page` with the newly created class above.

```
public partial class WebFormTest : NewPage
{
}
```

This way i can access all methods on *all* pages that inherit NewPage.

I would like to add a second class which would contain additional methods but to be applied to *some* pages. So created the below

```
public class MyHelper : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void DoSomething
    {
    }
}
```

and then tried to change

```
public partial class WebFormTest : NewPage, MyHelper
{
}
```

but this wasnt possible. I tried to remove the namespace System.Web.UI.Page on the second class but that didnt help. How could/should i access this second class on relevant pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public partial class WebFormTest : NewPage, MyHelper

This does not work because in .NET every class can ever only inherit from ONE other class. A class can implement multiple interfaces not inherit from multiple classes.

So, `MyHelper` should be either below `NewPage`, or above `NewPage` IF you want it to be IN the hierarchy. There is no rule that a class hierarchy can not be multiple levels deep.

i.e.

```
public class MyHelper : System.Web.UI.Page
```

should turn into

```
public class MyHelper : NewPage
```

though if those are really generic helper functions, not having them in the hirarchy ma be better. Extension methods are a way, or adding a property to an instance of the helper class.

Comment: I decided to add a property instead so the original functionality remains as is. Thanks for that. Just another quick one, can the property under NewPage have to be a new instance or can i tweak the original helper class? I did add a constructor but i dont know if this would cause memory leaks in future